# PDF not loading in Microsoft IE and Microsoft Edge

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, pdf, microsoft-edge

Thanks for always being supportive. I have come across an issue. I have some study materials(.PDF) embedded into my webpage . Not in the `<iframe>` but a customized class for PDF viewing for security purpose. Now the problem here is that I can view the PDF's in Firefox and Chrome but not on Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer 11. What could be the possible reason for this. My website is live on server and I came up to know this when the candidates couldn't read files.
Here is my code for displaying on my page,

```
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       <div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer" oncontextmenu="return false" data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_pdf", $chapterId) ; ?>"></div>
    </div>
```

And the pdf-viewer class,

```
.pdf-viewer {

  background: #909090;

  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  height: 400px;

  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

     -moz-border-radius: 4px;

          border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}
```

I would like to repeat here, I can view files properly in Firefox and Chrome but not in MS Edge and Internet Explorer 11. Any help would be really helpful and highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using the `<object>` tag To load the PDF

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried using `<object>` but that does not solves the issue.

Comment: `pdf-viewer class`, this is just CSS, not a class.  Well not what I think of as a class anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your time. What modification can be done? @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 0):

Working in IE-11  and Edge... Try it. It may help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF View</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <style> 
      .pdf-viewer {
          background: #909090;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          height: 1000px;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
         -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
         <div>
            <object data="n1.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="auto" id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer">

            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the concern you shown. But let me point out that now as the PDF's are displaying , it seems they can be saved. As I mentioned in my question part, I don't want the documents to be downloaded. Using `data-url` as the original code has shown is being used to stop the document from downloading and if in the `<object>` tag I use `data-url` , the space gets blank.

Comment: Can there be any other alternative solution to this?? @RaviShrimali